# Open source audio manipulation software

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, manipulation

Does anyone know a **free**, **command line**, **open source** audio manipulation software for Linux? The primary usage is to distort/scramble a recorded voice. I've tried [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) but it seems to lack features for my task.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about the features you are looking for, but did you tried those ?

- [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)
- [Sweep](http://www.metadecks.org/software/sweep/index.html)
- [Rezound](http://rezound.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: thank you, all three seems to be graphical though without any extensive support for the command line.